# How to simulate error for document.save() in mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

DB: Mongo ODM: I am using Mongoose as the ODM.

I am writing negative tests for document.save() function for my app. How do I simulate or replicate an error while saving the document so that I can assert accordingly.

```
const CreateArtist = async (artist) => {
    try {
        await dbConnect();
        const user = await new Artist(artist);
        await user.validate();
        return await user.save(); // want to test for error on save.
    } catch (err) {
        throw err;
    }
};
```

I have tried changing the connection string, but I got the connection string wrong error. I am unsure how to replicate the error on save.

Comment: You can use a mocking tool such as Sinon.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try writing a pre-save function that returns an error:

```
user.pre('save', function(next) {
    return next(new Error('myCustomError'));
});
user.save() // throws myCustomError
```

adapted from the docs [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html)